# pgfplots+fillbetween code no longer compiles correctly

Tags: pgfplots, incompatibility, fillbetween

I recently dug up some old code and it doesn't compile the way it used to. Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\pgfplotsset{width=5cm,height=5cm,compat=newest}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture} 
  \begin{scope}[local bounding box=sa]
  \begin{axis}[
    very thick,
    axis y line=center,
    axis x line=center,
    xtick=\empty,
    ytick=\empty,
    ymin=-.7,ymax=6,
    xmin=-4,xmax=4
  ]
  \addplot[red,domain=-4:4,samples=100]{ .35*x^2 };
  \addplot[name path=A,blue,samples=100]{ .75*x^2 };
  \addplot[name path=B,blue,samples=100]{ .1*x^2 };
  \addplot[blue!40] fill between[of=A and B];
  \end{axis}
  \end{scope}

  \draw ($ (sa.north east) + (.1,.1) $) rectangle ($ (sa.south west) + (-.1,-.1) $);        
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Here is what the code used to produce:
[image: what it should look like]
And here is what it produces now:
[image: what it looks like now]

A few things:

- even though i specified "very thick" in the axis description, the lines are no longer thick. If I comment out the 'fill between' line (last line before \end{axis}), then the lines return to correct thickness.
- the bounding box around the plot is the wrong size; there is now some extra space to the right. This also gets fixed if I comment out the 'fill between' line.
- clearly the fill between command isn't working. But I can get the fill to reappear if I comment out the 'scope' environment, but the line thicknesses are still messed up and the extra space is still there.

I get the desired result when I use an older system (e.g. works on Overleaf.com, which I believe uses texlive 2014). But if I try with Miktex 2.9 or texlive 2015 (both with all packages updated as of today) I get the garbage result.

What might be going on here?

Comment: The `scope` is messing with `fill between`: if you comment it, the area is filled.

Comment: For the record: "line width" stuff bug is already reported [here](https://sourceforge.net/p/pgfplots/bugs/138/), the bounding box stuff should be fixed and the fill between does not work because it is not allowed to scope `set layers` which is used for `fill between` (see [PGFPlots manual section 4.27.2 on page 404 (v1.14)](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgfplots/doc/pgfplots.pdf#page=404)).

Answer (score 2):

As you already guessed, you stumbled into a regression, i.e. a change in behavior / bugs introduced in the fillbetween library.

The issues are tracked as

- https://sourceforge.net/p/pgfplots/bugs/138/ (line width issue)
- https://sourceforge.net/p/pgfplots/bugs/196/ (fill between vanishes)
- a (deleted) comment refers to https://sourceforge.net/p/pgfplots/bugs/122/ (issues of fillbetween combined with group plots)

I as package author am sorry for your pain and will look for these issues.

Comment: Hi Christian, just to piggyback on this answer, do you ever consider moving things to GitHub ?

Comment: Hi Percusse, thanks for your interest in this topic! Migrating an entire environment comes with high cost ... and it appears to have little gain (if any?) compared to what I have now, and keeping the current solution has no cost for me. I'd rather invest my spare time in the implementation than the infrastructure. So: It is planned to stick with sourceforge for now.

Comment: That's certainly true but that would make the contributions much easier as it is the defacto open-source point as sourceforge once was. But now you can actually create a test suite and others can contribute code which is tested to the same tests you would perform and so on. It is indeed a bit of overhead but even LaTeX team is now on Github ;)

Comment: You are right, test servers are (appear to be?) free for opensource projects... that is, indeed, an interesting option which provides a significant benefit... I will think about it.